# Do I need to consume pubsub messages?

Tags: toit

I want to react on pubsub messages from the cloud.

However, I don't care for the content of the message. It's just used as a trigger. I would just go ahead and write an app yaml file that uses the trigger to launch my entry point.

Do I still need to consume the message in my application, or can they be safely ignored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not consume your messages they will be deleted after 7 days