# How do I reset unacknowledged messages in PubSub?

Tags: toit

The PubSub tab of the console shows that there is a message that wasn't acknowledged (probably answering my question on whether one needs to acknowledge pubsub messages: [Do I need to consume pubsub messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66903963/do-i-need-to-consume-pubsub-messages)).

How do I reset the unacknowledged messages?

The device has the following code:

```
import pubsub

TOPIC ::= "<MY_TOPIC>"

main:
  print "wakeup - checking messages"
  pubsub.subscribe TOPIC --blocking=false: | msg/pubsub.Message |
    print "Received message"
  print "done processing all messages"
```

But that doesn't seem to consume older messages that were there before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Messages will automatically be retried after a certain duration.

We have a 10 min acknowledgement deadline and messages that has not been acknowledged within that period will be retried.

Comment: When will they be retried? I think I have a subscription that is now several days old, but I don't think it has been retried.